# PowerPoint 365 reading order warning persists even when slide master layout and slide are correct

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I am remediating PowerPoint slides produced by a client to make the slides compliant with Section 508 (non-US users, this an accessibility standard). They are several years old, maybe the 2016 release, and the authors clearly did not know how to use master slide layouts. I am working in Office 365, and I finally created a new master and set of layouts and have been copying and pasting the content into a fresh slide deck. However, when I run the accessibility checker, nearly every slide gets flagged by a Reading Order warning even though I have checked and made sure that the reading order is correct in both the slide layout AND the slide. I have spent hours over a number of days trying to fix this problem and have hit a wall. Has anyone encountered this issue?

Thanks-

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ignore the Community Bot; it apparently doesn't know much about PPT but still complains about what it doesn't understand. AI with Dunning-Kreuger syndrome!  Your question is perfectly clear but hard to answer w/o seeing an example of what's going on. Can you post a sample presentation in the cloud, one that includes  just a few problem slides (even if the text itself is replaced with something non-proprietary) and post the link here, please?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this many times and think I have worked out what is happening. The Checker is looking at the location of the text on the slide, and really wants you to work from the top of the slide to the bottom. I have rearranged elements on the slide to fit with what PPT wants and the checker has finally given the ok.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).